# random screen display with kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, kivy

i am trying to make an app, a game actually that will display random screens when the "NEXT" button is touched, so i made the screens and the labels to be displayed on each screen but i cant get it to display a random screen when the "NEXT" button is touched, it just follows a pattern, would anyone help me here? heres the code:

```
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#: import Image kivy.uix.image.Image
#: import SoundLoader kivy.core.audio.SoundLoader


ScreenManagement:

    transition: FadeTransition()

    MainScreen:

    GameScreen:

    GameScreen2:

    GameScreen3:

    GameScreen4:


<Button>:

    font_size: 12
    size_hint: 0.2, 0.1

<MainScreen>:


    name: "main"

    FloatLayout:

    Button:

        text: "START GAME"
        color: 1,0,1,1
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y":0}
        on_release: app.root.current = "game"

    Button:

        text: "QUIT"
        color: 1,0,0,1
        pos_hint: {"x": .8, "y": 0}
        on_release: quit()

    Button:
        text: "SOUND"
        color: 0,1,0,1
        pos_hint: {"x":.2 , "y": .4}
        on_press: app.play_sound1()

<GameScreen>:
    name: "game"

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Python\nSnowden\nMr.Robot"
            font_size: 40
            color: 0,1,0,1
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "y": 0}


    Button:

        text: "Home"
        on_release: app.root.current = "main"
        color: 1,0,0,1
        pos_hint: {"right":1, "top":1}

    Button:

        text: "Next"
        on_release: app.root.current = "game2"
        color: 0,1,0,1
        pos_hint: {"x":0, "y":0}

<GameScreen2>:
    name: "game2"

    FloatLayout:

        Label:
            text: "Banana\n\nOrange\n\nTea\n\nSleep"
            font_size: 40
            color: 0,1,0,1
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "y": 0}

    Button: 

        text: "Home"
        on_release: app.root.current = "main"
        color: 1,0,0,1
        pos_hint: {"right":1, "top":1}

    Button:

        text: "Next"
        on_release: app.root.current = "game3"
        color: 0,1,0,1
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": 0}

<GameScreen3>:
    name: "game3"

    FloatLayout:

        Label:
            text: "Assembly\n\nRuby\n\nC"
            font_size: 40
            color: 0,1,0,1
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "y":0}

    Button: 

        text: "Home"
        on_release: app.root.current = "main"
        color: 1,0,0,1
        pos_hint: {"right":1, "top":1}

    Button:

        text: "Next"
        on_release: app.root.current = "game4"
        color: 0,1,0,1
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": 0}

<GameScreen4>:
    name: "game4"

    FloatLayout:

        Label:
            text: "Prolog\n\nPygame\n\nC++"
            font_size: 40
            color: 0,1,0,1
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "y":0}

    Button: 

        text: "Home"
        on_release: app.root.current = "main"
        color: 1,0,0,1
        pos_hint: {"right":1, "top":1}
```

the above is the kv code, sorry for the mess im an amateur when it comes to kivy
and heres the python side code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class GameScreen(Screen):
    pass

class GameScreen2(Screen):
    pass

class GameScreen3(Screen):
    pass

class GameScreen4(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("quora.kv")

class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):

        self.load_sounds()

        return presentation

    def load_sounds(self):
        self.sounds = {}
        for i in range(10):
            fname = 'sound' + str(i+1) + '.wav'
            self.sounds[i] = SoundLoader.load(fname)

    def play_sound1(self):
        sound = self.sounds.get(0)
        if sound is not None:
            sound.volume = 0.5
            sound.play()

    def play_sound2(self):
        sound = self.sounds.get(1)
        if sound is not None:
            sound.volume = 0.5
            sound.play()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    MainApp().run()
```

this is the sample i made for you because the original one is way bigger than this i dont know how to use somewhat of a LOOP to generate screen so i made more that 20 screens on the original code so, and if you could help me figure out how can i STOP THE MENU SONG when i hit the "START" BUTTON, so that i can hit the "SONG" BUTTON on SCREEN1 to PLAY its SONG i would be gratefull. thanks you for the patience.

Comment: Very confusing post. Your post starts by asking about how to  `display a random screen`. Then at the end, you ask about `how can i STOP THE MENU SONG when i hit the "START" BUTTON`. What is your question (Please, just one at a time).

Comment: sorry for the confusion i didnt mean to, so the main problem is the screens i am try to make game that every time i hit "NEXT" it will show a a random screen with its label, but i just managed to make the game to follow a pattern it goes the same way everytime screen1 screen2 screen3 when i hit "NEXT", now i want it to go to a random screen when i hit the "NEXT" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Display random screens when the "NEXT" button is touched

### Use [screen_names](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager.screen_names)

> screen_names
>
> List of the names of all the [Screen](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen) widgets added. The list is
>   read only.
>
> screens_names is an [AliasProperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.AliasProperty) and is read-only. It is updated
>   if the screen list changes or the name of a screen changes.

### Snippets

```
#:import choice random.choice
...

    Button:

        text: "Next"
        on_release: 
            root.manager.current = choice(root.manager.screen_names[1:])
        color: 0,1,0,1
        pos_hint: {"x":0, "y":0}
```

## Stop / Play Music

You might want to use a [ToggleButton](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.togglebutton.html) instead of Button for playing music. Please refer to the example below.

## Example

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class MusicScreen(Screen):
    enter = ObjectProperty(None)
    text_input = ObjectProperty(None)
    stop = ObjectProperty(None)
    musicbutton = ToggleButton()


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MainApp(App):
    sound = ObjectProperty(None, allownone=True)

    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()

    def on_state(self, state, filename):
        print("ONSTATE!!!")
        print("\tstate=", state)

        if self.sound is None:
            self.sound = SoundLoader.load(filename)

        # stop the sound if it's currently playing
        if self.sound.status != 'stop':
            self.sound.stop()

        if state == "down":
            self.sound.volume = .5
            self.sound.play()
        else:   # if state == "normal":
            if self.sound:
                self.sound.stop()
                # self.sound.unload()
                self.sound = None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

### main.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0

<ScreenManagement>:
    MusicScreen:
        name: 'music'

<MusicScreen>:
    text_input: text_input
    id: "music"
    name: "music"

    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooserListView:
            id: filechooser
            rootpath: "/home/iam/Music/"
            on_selection: text_input.text = self.selection and self.selection[0] or ''

        TextInput:
            id: text_input
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            multiline: False

        ToggleButton:
            size_hint: 1, .2
            text: "Play/Stop By File"
            on_state: app.on_state(self.state, text_input.text)

        ToggleButton:
            id: musicbutton
            size_hint: 1, .2
            text: "Play/Stop By Title"
            on_state: app.on_state(self.state, text_input.text)
```

Comment: For the random screens, I think you could also use `root.manager.current = random.choice(root.manager.screen_names)`.

Comment: interesting, let me try it out and ill post the result. thank you.

Comment: yup it worked, i used the snippet above to guide me through the process and its working, now im going to complete this game. thank you all so much. when i finish it ill make sure to send it to all of you :)